# Drawing in a bitmap sometimes gets screwedup

Tags: java, android, canvas, bitmap

I have a android that draws a mandelbrot image.

I have 16 threads that each draw 1/16 part of the image, they have their own bitmap.

```
    for(int x=0;x<xw;x++) {
        for(int y=0;y<yh;y++) {
            c_real=realMin+((double)(x+x1)*scaleReal);
            c_imag=imagMin+((double)(y+y1)*scaleImag);
            tmp=cal_pixel(c_real, c_imag, mag);
            while(pause[thread]) {
                try{
                    Thread.sleep(5);
                }catch(InterruptedException ie){

                }
            }
            plot(x,y,c[tmp], thread);
            active[thread]=true;
        }
        dirty=true;
    }

public void plot(int x, int y, int c, int myId) {
    bitmap[myId].setPixel(x, y, c);
}
```

The run method for each piece

```
public void run() {
    int myId=id++;
    Log.i("run","Starting thread "+myId);
    while(true) {
        if (redraw[myId]) {
            Log.i("run","redraw");
            calc(myId);
            redraw[myId]=false;
        }
        try{
            Thread.sleep(100);
        }catch(InterruptedException ie) {
        }
    }
}
```

I have a separate thread that 10 times a second takes the bitmaps and draws them on the canvas.

```
        image.pause(true);
        for(int i=0;i<16;i++) {
            c.drawBitmap(image.getBitmap(i), (i%4)*w/4, (i/4)*h/4, null);
        }
        image.pause(false);
```

This is the thread that draws them

```
public void run() {
    Canvas c;
    while (true) {
        if (run) {
            if (view.dirty()) {
                c = null;
                try {
                    c = holder.lockCanvas(null);
                    synchronized (holder) {
                        view.onDraw(c);
                    }
                } finally {
                    // do this in a finally so that if an exception is thrown
                    // during the above, we don't leave the Surface in an
                    // inconsistent state
                    if (c != null) {
                        holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
                    }
                }
            }
            try{
                Thread.sleep(100);
            }catch(InterruptedException ie){

            }
        }else{
            //Log.i("Waiting the night away","Waiting the night away");
            try{
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }catch(InterruptedException ie){

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Sometimes one or several of these pieces gest screwed up and are not drawn to the canvas, any idea why that happense.

It worked better in android 2.3.x it almost never happened, but noww in android 4.x it happens qquite often, if you want to check the program out and experience the bug here is the link https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=se.klockar.mandelbrotmobile

Comment: I downloaded and tried your app. I played with it quite a bit on a Xoom running 4.1 and I only saw the issue once. It looks like the thread is dying and not finishing its work. Do you have code ensuring that all of the threads completed succesfully?

Comment: I also noticed that I only got updates for a couple of seconds.  Then the entire image would just sit there partially finished.  When the background processes finish, I get one last update that painted the entire image.

Comment: I do not allow the threads to die at all. I'll add the thread code.